# Sufficient condition of $K'/K$ is ramified extension

Tags: field-theory, local-field, ramification

> Let $K$ be a local field and $K'$ be it's finite extension. And there
> exists $a∈K'$ such that $v(a)$ is not integer.
>
> Then, ramification index $e$ of $K'/K$ is at least 2, in other words, $K'/K$ is ramified extension.

I heard this holds from definition of ramification index, https://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/lf.ramification_index.

But I'm having trouble. I tried to use another characterization of ramification index, but in vain.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4250367/96384?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $v$ is normalized in such a way so that the value group of $v$ on $K$ is $\Bbb Z$. Let $\pi$ be a prime element of $K$. Note that $K'/K$ is unramified iff $\pi$ is also a prime of $K'$. If $K'/K$ were unramified $\pi$ would still be a prime of $K'^\times$, so every element $a$ of $K'$ has a decomposition $\pi^mu$ for some unit $u\in\mathcal O_{K'}^\times$, in particular $m=v(a)\in\Bbb Z$. Thus, if some $a\in K'^\times$ has non-integral valuation the extension has to be ramified.
The same argument shows that if the ramification index is $e$, then the value group of $v$ on $K'$ is $\frac{1}{e}\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I'm confused. $v$ is valuation on $K$, and $a$ is not necessarily in $K$, what do you mean by $v(a)$? Are you thinking some kind of extension of valuation ?

Comment: You wrote $v(a)$ in your question, so I assumed that $v$ is already defined on $K'$. If we only know $v$ is defined on $K$ it can be extended uniquely to a valuation of $K'$ (due to the completeness of $K$).